# How to subscribe to all events in the system in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-event-bridge

I am working on AWS.

I have a core system that needs to execute something on every event published in the system.
I would like to config an SNS or SQS that will be subscribed to all events
and when there is a new event it will be subscribed automatically to it as well.

Is it possible?

I was looking on EventBridge capabillities including pipes but didn't see it possible

Comment: What kind of events are you describing?  Are you creating the events?  Are they coming from something else ... ?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, if you don't put a filter in a Pipe or only use `{"account": ["<your_account_id>"]}` in an Event Bus rule, it will match all events available (sent to) the Pipe/Bus.